# how to put the text below the image

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I'm wondering how can I make the text in the center just like the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <img src="http://www.wikima4.com/assets/templates/wikima4/css/images/red.jpg" width=
    "1200" height="150" />
  </center>

  <div align="justified">
    <font size="3" face="calibri">text text text text The quick brown fox jumps over the
    lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over
    the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps
    over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog<br />
    <br />
    You can download the documentation from this link: Download</font>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align:center;`?
`<center>`?
`margin:0 auto`?

Check out this. http://jsfiddle.net/VnRRA/ Is it what you want?

update: http://jsfiddle.net/VnRRA/1/

Basically what I did was, gave the parent div an id`centerize` and told it to `text-align:center;`

Comment: I just posted the code. I don't know what happened it erased the one I posted

Comment: Is it possible to have it aligned in the center?

Comment: I noticed that you added in the CSS field centerize. What if I only have the text pad as html? where shall I add it on my html code?

Comment: you can put it right below the `<title>` tag. See here http://jsfiddle.net/VnRRA/3/

Comment: @andrek: Thanks now it's ok. But is it possible to have it align all the text. In the code it's like building an inverted triangle.

Comment: with this: jsfiddle.net/VnRRA/2 this is ok. But what I don't understand is, why the text : "this link: Download" has more indention?

Comment: It is too short, that is why it indents. you can try align left like this http://jsfiddle.net/VnRRA/4/

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this for multiple images, you can also use a table with one row as the text and another for the image. With this method, you can place the text above or below the images. i.e.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="CSS Settings"> image 1 </td>
        <td class="CSS Settings"> image 2 </td>
        <td class="CSS Settings"> image 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="CSS Settings"> Text for image 1 </td>
        <td class="CSS Settings"> Text for image 2 </td>
        <td class="CSS Settings"> Text for image 3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```